# React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, rerender

I'm using react js to show locations on map. and get the coords from a json file. I set up a button to select each.then when the coords are selected I have to rerender to display new info I've just got. but I have an error says :
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

```
  const data = UserParents.all.children;

class App extends Component{


 state = {
greenIcon : {
  lat: 51.505,
  lng: -0.09,
},
zoom: 13,

   }
greenIcon = L.icon({
iconUrl : leafGreen ,
shadowUrl : leafShadow ,
iconSize:     [38, 95],
shadowSize:   [50, 64],
iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
 });
      handleClick (userId) {

    if (userId == 3966){
        this.state.greenIcon.lat = User3966.coords[0].lat;
        this.state.greenIcon.lng = User3966.coords[0].lng;
    }else if (userId == 3967) {
        this.state.greenIcon.lat = User3967.coords[0].lat;
        this.state.greenIcon.lng = User3967.coords[0].lng;
    }else if (userId == 3968) {
        this.state.greenIcon.lat = User3968.coords[0].lat;
        this.state.greenIcon.lng = User3968.coords[0].lng;
    }else if (userId == 3969) {
        this.state.greenIcon.lat = User3969.coords[0].lat;
        this.state.greenIcon.lng = User3969.coords[0].lng;
    }else if (userId == 3970) {
        this.state.greenIcon.lat = User3970.coords[0].lat;
        this.state.greenIcon.lng = User3970.coords[0].lng;
    }

    this.forceUpdate();
}


  render() {

const positionGreenIcon = [this.state.greenIcon.lat, this.state.greenIcon.lng]
return (
    <div className="App">
         <div>
            {
                Object.keys(data).map((key)=>(
                    <div>
                        <h4>{data[key].name}</h4>
                        <h4>{key}</h4>
                        <button onClick={this.handleClick()}>Select</button>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                ))
            }
         </div>
      <Map className='map' center={positionGreenIcon} zoom={this.state.zoom} >
        <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={positionGreenIcon} icon={this.greenIcon}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </Map>
    </div>
);
 }
}
    export default App;
```

Comment: Remove `this.forceUpdate()`

Comment: but how can I rerender ?

Comment: First of all, read official document's basic concept carefully, your change on `props` and `state` will cause automatic re-render. AND, you shall never set `state` by directly giving value to it, use `this.setState({ XXX: value })` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The error in this case is that the onClick event has to be called with a callback, if not, the function is constantly instanced every render, so in this case

```
onClick={()=>this.handleClick()}
```

And of course, read the basic documentation from the website of React, because your code is full of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone one of these is the problem: `this.state.greenIcon.lat = User3966.coords[0].lat;`

In react you don't change the state object directly.  You need to call the `this.setState` function.  When you do that, the state changes, and the component updates and rerenders.  Setting state the way you're doing it is incorrect, and React will not know to re-render your components based on your state changes.

Follow keikai's advice and spend some time in the React documentation.  [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is the section on `setState`

Answer (score 0):

try alternate `onClick={this.handleClick()}` by `onClick = {this.handleClick}` or `onClick= {()=> this.handleClick()}`